# golang execute function at exactly every 1 millisecond over 1 second ( 1000 call per second)

Tags: go, milliseconds

I am new to golang.

I want to call a function at exactly 1 milliseconds for a certain duration ( 1 second for now ) , the function should be called 1000 time a seconds .

I did follow and implemented multiple approaches using timer and tick , but when testing on a simple function that just increment by one a value every time it's been called I find out that it's only been called about ~630 time in 1 second .

When I call the function in loop and stop it after 1 second , The function is called about ~ 226370427 time in 1 second , which means I have problem with the timer and tick .

Here is my code that I implemented using goroutine concurrency which keeps calling the function that increment every 1 ms using ticker and stopped after 1 second by the main and the sum value is then read using the int channel.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tickChan := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 1).C

    doneChan := make(chan bool)
    resultChan := make(chan int)
    go start(tickChan, doneChan, resultChan)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    doneChan <- true // Set it to true to stop the infinte loop in the routine
    fmt.Printf("total is : %v\n", <-resultChan)

}

func start(tickChan <-chan time.Time, doneChan <-chan bool, resultChan chan int) {
    sum := 0 // <-- The the value to increment
    for {
        select {
        case <-tickChan:
            sum++
        case <-doneChan:
            resultChan <- sum
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to do it in node.js successfully (using nanotimer lib ) and was able to run exactly 1000 in 1 sec for every 1 ms , I was even to do it in microsecond too (tho it was about ~ 988676 in 1 second instead of 1 million )

Edit :

Here is my go version `go version go1.10.2 windows/amd64`

and go env 
`

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\name\Documents\Go Projects
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build403228958=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

`

EDIT 2 : I tested it on the playground and manged to get 1000 total , I think the issue is with windows .Any way to fix it ?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue: `total is : 1000`. Add the output from the `go version` and `go env` commands to your question.

Comment: You also have to remember that goroutines are multiplexed over OS threads, and cooperatively scheduled. For instance, there's no synchronization at the start of the goroutine, so there's no guarantee of when the for loop will actually start during the 1 second sleep. Synchronizing the start may make it more reliable, but you're not really guaranteed to get exactly 1000 ticks if the runtime ends up scheduling other goroutines. It's much simpler to tick a loop every millisecond in a single threaded event loop.

Comment: I tested it on the playground and manged to get 1000 total , I think the issue is with windows .Any way to fix it ?

Comment: @Nitro: What version of Windows are you using? I am able to approximate your results on Windows 10. On Windows 7, I get lows in the 980s and highs in the 990s. On Linux, native Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, and Windows 10 WSL Ubuntu 18.04, I get 1000. WSL uses shims to translate Linux syscalls to Windows syscalls.

Comment: @peterSO I am using windows 10 build 17134 ( latest I believe ) .can you achieve microseconds accuracy ? running every 1 micro to achieve 1,000,000 call in 1 second ?

Answer (score 2):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [type Ticker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker)
>
> A Ticker holds a channel that delivers `ticks' of a clock at
>   intervals.
>
> ```
> type Ticker struct {
>         C <-chan Time // The channel on which the ticks are delivered.
>         // contains filtered or unexported fields
> }
> ```
>
> [func NewTicker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker)
>
> ```
> func NewTicker(d Duration) *Ticker
> ```
>
> NewTicker returns a new Ticker containing a channel that will send the
>   time with a period specified by the duration argument. It adjusts the
>   intervals or drops ticks to make up for slow receivers. The duration d
>   must be greater than zero; if not, NewTicker will panic. Stop the
>   ticker to release associated resources.

---

Here are my results for Windows 10.0.17134 and Linux 4.15 from the same dual-booted machine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func ticker(tick time.Duration) {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(tick)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    done := make(chan bool)
    sleep := 1 * time.Second
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(sleep)
        done <- true
    }()
    ticks := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            fmt.Printf("%v × %v ticks in %v\n", ticks, tick, sleep)
            return
        case <-ticker.C:
            ticks++
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("GOMAXPROCS:", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))
    start := time.Duration(1 * time.Millisecond)
    end := start / 1000
    for tick := start; tick >= end; tick /= 10 {
        ticker(tick)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112]:

GOMAXPROCS: 4
554 × 1ms ticks in 1s
552 × 100µs ticks in 1s
542 × 10µs ticks in 1s
552 × 1µs ticks in 1s

Linux 4.15.0-23-generic:

GOMAXPROCS: 4
1000 × 1ms ticks in 1s
9990 × 100µs ticks in 1s
13169 × 10µs ticks in 1s
14014 × 1µs ticks in 1s
```

---

> [Sleep function | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep)
>
> Suspends the execution of the current thread until the time-out
>   interval elapses.
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> dwMilliseconds
> ```
>
> The time interval for which execution is to be suspended, in
>   milliseconds.

---

On Windows, the Go Ticker resolution is likely limited to, at best, a millisecond.

Comment: "On Windows, the Go Ticker resolution is likely limited to, at best, a millisecond." Likely more: the test file for `time.Sleep` [defines](https://golang.org/src/time/sleep_test.go#L24) `windowsInaccuracy` to be 17 ms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, via CGo.

You would have to configure a '/dev/rtc1' resource, and set it to the desired frequency.  Then, use the 'read()' C library call to get a 1 millisecond pause.  Only 1, administrator, user can execute this.

This is platform-specific.

In Windows, you'll need to find another way to access the clock chip to do this.